# Allow bash script to be run as root, but not sudo

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo, root

I'm new here and new to bash/linux.

My teacher gave me an assignment to allow a script to be run only when you're "really" root and not when you're using sudo. After two hours of searching and trying I'm beginning to think he's trolling me. Allowing only root is easy, but how do I exclude users that run it with sudo?

This is what I have:

```
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "You must be root to run this script."
  exit
fi
```

Comment: try this: `sudo whoami`... I'm not sure that the problem is defined particularly clearly. `sudo whoami` claims you're root. Even if that doesn't count, what if you run a shell with sudo, does that count as using sudo?

Comment: Take away sudo all and enumerate only the commands a user should be allowed to run as root, excluding your script from that list.

Comment: How would you stop the `sudo` user from removing the restriction from the script once you have put it in place? There is no difference between the root user logged in from a console and the root user accessing the system via `sudo`.  The foolproof solution woud be to simply uninstall `sudo`.

Comment: I think that any answer has to consider the possibility that the lecturer is ignoring (or hasn't thought of) the possibility of running  sudo su  and intends that the solution prevents the script from starting to run rather than aborting if it doesn't like its execution environment. As such I agree with @mikem and would highlight  man sudoers  -> SECURITY NOTES since some of their caveats aren't relevant if the script can't be edited or renamed.

Comment: your best bet is to restrict users to not be able to execute the script via sudo, using answer https://superuser.com/a/735286/174998

Comment: Is the root user to be allowed to execute the script through `sudo`?

Comment: On any secure system, there are no shared accounts.  There will be no such thing as "really" root - the actual user will ***always*** be known.  Limitations like this are worse than useless - they give you a false sense of security when all they really do is maybe slow down malicious actors for a few seconds.  You'll think you're secure while in reality you're being pwned by every half-wit with an internet connection who can spell "Google".

Comment: I can see a couple of possibilities here. 1. Your teacher is an idiot who didn't/doesn't realize how hard it would be, or how fragile his/her pet "solution" really is. 2. Your teacher is using this as an example to demonstrate the inadequacy of the students attempted solutions. 3. Your teacher is a jerk who decided to throw a neophyte to the wolves just for fun (you mention the trolling possibility in your question). In any case, I question the motives behind such an assignment...

Comment: Nothing about `sudo` *requires* it to give you root access; that's just the default behavior everyone is familiar with. `sudo` can be configured to allow you to do only *very* specific things, including not gain root access at all.

Comment: @JaredSmith: He probably wants an anti-bonehead solution not a secure solution. Else sudo-user could copy the script and take the check out.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd By running `sudo su -`, than `screen` detach an re-attach, You'll be in a *root login shell*. See [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626764/27653)

Comment: @chepner I've cited your comment in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626764/27653)

Comment: @FHauri I know you can get a shell, and so apparently do you. But as I explicitly said: the lecturer might not, or might be attempting to not ask that question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The only way I could think of is to check one of the `SUDO_*` environment
variables set by sudo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]
then
    if [ -n "$SUDO_USER" ]
    then
        printf "This script has to run as root (not sudo)\n" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    printf "OK, script run as root (not sudo)\n"
else
    printf "This script has to run as root\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Notice that of course this solution is not future proof as you cannot stop
anyone from setting a variable before running the script:

```
$ su
Password:
# SUDO_USER=whatever ./root.sh
This script has to run as root (not sudo)
# ./root.sh
OK, script run as root (not sudo)
```

Comment: +1, but this can still be tricked by something like `sudo bash -c 'unset SUDO_USER=; my_command;'`. I would not rely on it.

Comment: It might not be good for actual work, but it will probably get my assignment done, which is what matters at the moment. Thank you very much!

Comment: The paranoids among us would begin with `env | grep -E 'SUDO|PPID|PID`, and validate each via `/usr/bin/ps` and other command line tools. One could check each of `env | sort`, if one wished.

Comment: Care! If user run `sudo su -`, variables `SUDO_*` doesn't  exist anymore! See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626764/27653

Comment: Care, if user run `screen`,. detach then re-attach, you can't see anything more than a *root login shell*!! See last paragraph at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626764/27653

Answer (score 19):

Another option would be to check if the grandparent process name is "sudo":

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]
then
  if [ $(ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $$)) = "sudo" ]
  then
    echo Running under sudo
  else
    echo Running as root and not via sudo
  fi
else
  echo Not running as root
fi
```

Comment: This fails when run under "sudo su" or "sudo bash". I think you need to check multiple levels of processes.

Comment: Granted; you could extend this to loop over the PPID process tree, but I thought I'd cover the most common usage of `./script` or `sudo ./script`, to point out the core idea of checking for "sudo" as being the parent process or not.

Comment: This can be circumvented by sudoing then running a process that disowns right?

Comment: This answer attempts to address the question "how do I exclude users that run it with sudo?" in the straightforward interpretation, not as an exhaustive security measure. I don't know what the professor was aiming for, but maybe   parent processes were on the syllabus and they thought this would be an instructive exercise. Any simple measure can be fooled, as we've seen so far with the straightforward SUDO_USER environment variable and these process checks.

Answer (score 13):

The information about which user logged in is available in `/proc/self/loginuid`. **EDIT** *due to comments: That file does not seem to exist on all systems. I tested and it is available on Centos 6, Fedora 32, Fedora 33 and Ubuntu 20.04, all in standard x86_64 setups.*
If we login as our user and than use `sudo` or `su` to become root, this will not change `/proc/self/loginuid` and it will be some non-zero value. If we directly log in as root, then `cat /proc/self/loginuid` will return `0`. <strike>Note that this file can NOT be modified, even root cannot do this.</strike> **EDIT** *due to Stéphane Chazelas' comment: Root can overwrite this file using `echo 0 > /proc/self/loginuid`. However, this can be prevented by setting `auditctl --loginuid-immutable`.*

The script to check for real root (if `auditctl --loginuid-immutable` is set) could look like

```
#!/bin/bash
loginuid=$(cat /proc/self/loginuid)
echo $loginuid
if [[ $loginuid -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "You did not log in as root."
    exit
fi
```

Comment: On Raspberry Pi OS (which is a Debian-based OS), this file doesn’t seem to exist

Comment: That's surprising. I checked Fedora 32, 33, Centos 6 and ubuntu 20.04 and they all have that file. I checked on x86_64 only, not on arm systems.

Comment: @NickKennedy FWIW it does not exist on my ODROID U3 (armhf xenial) as well

Comment: I believe this requires `CONFIG_AUDIT=y`, on Linux, but on such a system this is the right answer (though I imagine the actual goal was to read the manual and find SUDO_USER).

Comment: If you would like to see a script that defeats `/proc/self/loginuid` I think I can provide.

Comment: Update: I know I can provide. It's possible to convince init to re-exec itself, which means it's possible to convince init to re-exec anything you darn well please.

Comment: `sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > /proc/self/loginuid && cat /proc/self/loginuid'` outputs 0 for me on Ubuntu 20.04 with a 5.4.0-58-generic Linux kernel

Comment: Can be changed with `auditctl --loginuid-immutable`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the auditctl reminder. That explains why I could not change the loginuid on my system and was surprised about your comment.

Comment: @laolux: Although once I have root I can defeat it outright as I said earlier.

Comment: `auditctl --loginuid-immutable` doesn't make this perfect either. In particular, it only prevents you from changing your loginuid once it's been set, but there are ways that you can gain control of, or start, a process where it never gets set at all.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yes, but I could imagine restricting sudo to execute let's say bash only. That way it would automatically be set on your shell. However, I am not sure about inheritance rules, so there could be a loop.

Comment: @Joshua yes, on systemd it is very easy to re-exec init: `init u`. Unfortunately I do not know enough about systemd to know how to change the configuration, but I could imagine that changing the configuration may be restricted. For example, on Fedora kexec is outright blocked, so even root cannot do as it pleases.

Comment: Under bash, avoid useless `cat`! You could write `loginuid=$(</proc/self/loginuid)`. Then as math *greather than zero* is true: `(( loginuid )) && echo Must be root && exit 1`

Answer (score 6):

## Avoid `sudo` in *`root`* bash script?

### Preamble: *Care sharing root account*!!

Unfortunely, there is no resistant way... Please read carefuly upto last paragraph

Once you give root access to someone, they could do anything, including editing your script!!

For sample, if user hit `sudo su -`, then variables `SUDO_*` doesn't exist anymore...

### First quick way using `pstree`

So simplier way to search for `sudo` presence in whole current tree, seem to use `pstree`:

```
die() { echo >&2 ${0##*/} Error: "$@"; exit 1;}
pstree -s $$ | grep -q '\bsudo\b' && die "Can't be run under sudo"
```

### With `ps` only, you could loop over `ps ho ppid`:

```
die() { echo >&2 ${0##*/} Error: "$@"; exit 1;}
pid=$$
while read pid name foo < <(ps ho ppid,cmd $pid) && ((pid>1));do
    [ "$name" = "sudo" ] && die "Can't be run under sudo"
done
```

### Regarding comment about *renamed `sudo`*

If sudo command is renamed or copied, then instead of looking for command name, look for *UID* in whole parent tree. So script is same than previous, but searching for `UID >= 1000` in parent tree:

```
die() { echo >&2 ${0##*/} Error: "$@"; exit 1;}
pid=$$
while read pid uid < <(ps ho ppid,uid $pid) && ((pid>1));do
    ((uid>999)) && die "Can't be run under sudo"
done
```

#### Because we are speaking about *Un*x*

To be correct, avoid using fixed statical datas, use of `UID_MIN` from `/etc/login.defs`:

```
die() { echo >&2 ${0##*/} Error: "$@"; exit 1;}
while read fld val;do
    case $fld in UID_MIN ) UIDMIN=$val ;break ;; esac
done </etc/login.defs
((UIDMIN)) || die Getting UID_MIN.
pid=$$
while read pid uid < <(ps ho ppid,uid $pid) && ((pid>1));do
    (( uid >= UIDMIN )) && die "Can't be run under sudo"
done
```

### Workaround for executing this by using `sudo` anyway

But all this is someting *fragile*:

```
$ sudo su -
# screen -D -R  # apt install screen if not installed
```

Now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> , then <kbd>d</kbd> to be *detached*. Type `exit` or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to return in *user mode*...

Then simply:

```
$ sudo screen -x
```

Now, you'll be logged in a *root login* session. No trace of any sudo.

```
# ps $PPID
 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 26367 ?        Ss     0:00 SCREEN -D -R
# ps ho ppid $PPID
 1
# set | grep SUDO
                                         # <-- nothing here!
```

## Conclusion

As [chepner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22257/chepner) rightly [commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1172882?noredirect=1): sudo is drawn to give specifics access to specifics tools:

> Nothing about sudo requires it to give you root access; that's just the default behavior everyone is familiar with. sudo can be configured to allow you to do only very specific things, including not gain root access at all – [chepner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22257/chepner)

Care to configure them correctly, before using fragile workaround!

See:

```
apropos sudo
```

And read carefully

```
man sudo.conf
man sudoers
```

### Regarding `logname`

Have a look at correct [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626955/27653)! This could be the best answer for a *homework*!!

Again, lot of *workaround*, like: `echo 0 > /proc/self/loginuid`...

### About `/proc/self/loginuid` under ***Linux***

Please read interesting [laolux's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626762/27653) about this!

```
die() { echo >&2 ${0##*/} Error: "$@"; exit 1;}
read lUid </proc/self/loginuid || die "Can't access procfile"
((lUid)) && die "You must be logged as root."
```

( This syntax avoid forks! )

But anyway

- script could be copied and edited
- depending on config/kernel, this kernel entry could be spoofed
- *Sudoer* could create `cron` entry for initiating special `screen` session as *`root`*. (`cron` and `screen` are not the only way for doing things like this! Just the first coming to my mind. )

Comment: In common with other solutions, this fails if the sudo command has been renamed

Answer (score 4):

I suggest checking out process list strings and see if the user is running the program using `sudo`

```
contype=`tty | cut -d '/' -f 3`
tty="$contype/`tty | cut -d '/' -f 4`"

if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]
then
    res=`ps ax | grep "$tty" | grep "$0" | grep "sudo"`
    if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
        echo "You should not run the script using sudo!"
        exit 2
    else
        echo "Done."
    fi
else
    echo "You are not root. Run this script as root."
    exit 2
fi
```

That variable `res` is simply for you if you want to filter results again.

Arkadusz code is nice but unfortunately it can be bypassed really easy...

Comment: This fails if the user is logged in on `tty/1` or another physical  device.

Comment: Thanks for alerting me. I've edited the code...

Comment: Bypassable by running `screen` inside of sudo

Comment: Please try this: `IFS=/ read foo{,} tty < <(tty)`, then `ps --tty $tty fw`! Anyway, this fail if sudo is renamed, if user run `sudo su -`, then `screen`...

Answer (score 4):

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ] || [ "$(logname)" != root ]; then
  echo >&2 "You either don't have superuser privilege or didn't login as root"
  exit 1
fi
```

Not foolproof as any process with superuser privilege that can run any command can do anything to work around anything, but may be close to what the teacher's expecting and is standard.

Comment: Best attended answer, I think! You've been cited in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626764/27653)

Answer (score 2):

Just to post something completely different:

```
if ! tty -s 2>&0
then    echo "Need to run with standard error on a terminal"
        exit 1
fi

if [ x"`stat --printf=%u $(tty)`" != x"0" ]
then    echo "Must be logged in as root. Can't use sudo or su here."
        exit 1
fi
```

This works by checking if the terminal device of the logged-in user is owned by root. As with all other answers, it can be fooled if really desired.

Answer (score -2):

```
man sudoers
```

(the details may vary from system to system)

"The sudoers policy plugin determines a user's sudo privileges.  It is the default sudo policy plugin.  The policy is driven by the /etc/sudoers file..."

"The sudoers file is composed of two types of entries: aliases (basically variables) and user specifications (which specify who may run what)."

Remove all users from /etc/sudoers (details omitted), and the sudo command will not work for anyone. After that, only root can run commands that require the root privilege.

There are configuration options to allow a user to run commands except a particular command, and vice versa.

Please note that we are doing your homework for you and we should not do that again.

Comment: This misses the point of the question entirely.

Comment: @Mark I knew someone would say that. The question doesn't specify that the script itself has to "decide" who can run it, just that root can run it but not a sudo user. It occurred to me that this was what his instructor was looking for. Maybe I'm wrong.